# Viewing and modifying hex data in file

Tags: linux, hex-viewer

I want to view and edit hex data of specific files in linux. What would be a good program (open source preferred) which is able to do that and is compatible with most linux distros?

Comment: Do you have any additional requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GHex](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Ghex) or [Bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/). I would recommend Bless. You can edit both raw data and hexadecimal data.

If you use Ubuntu you can install it with `sudo apt-get install bless`.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hmm I cant seem to be able to install it says it needs packages from unauthenticated sources.

Comment: What Linux distro / version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Install the [getdeb](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb) package, do a 'sudo apt-get update' and try again. Hopefully that should do it. I have installed it with no problems in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

From [Need a good hex editor for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5498197/395857):

> **[wxHexEditor](http://www.wxhexeditor.org/) is a hex editor specially for big files.**
>
> - It uses 64 bit file descriptors (supports files or devices up to 2^64 bytes , means some exabytes but tested only 1 PetaByte file
>     (yet). ).
> - It does NOT copy whole file to your RAM. That make it FAST and can open files (which sizes are Multi Giga < Tera < Peta < Exabytes)
> - Could open your devices on Linux, Windows or MacOSX.
> - Memory Usage : Currently ~10 MegaBytes while opened multiple > ~8GB files.
> - Could operate thru XOR encryption.
> - Written with C++/wxWidgets GUI libs and can be used with other OSes such as Mac OS, Windows as native application.
> - You can copy/edit your Disks, HDD Sectors with it.( Usefull for rescue files/partitions by hand. )
> - You can delete/insert bytes to file, more than once, without creating temp file.
>
> [image]
>
> You can sort on Linux to find some more here: 
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 0):

You may try [`hexeditor.jar`](https://github.com/javadev/hexeditor), a binary file editor. Since it's written in Java, it should be compatible with most operating systems.

[image: javadev/hexeditor.jar]