# Hexadecimal diff viewer for Linux

Tags: linux, gui, diff

I am looking for a good hexadecimal viewer for Linux.

It should have a GUI and be intuitive to use.

It should also be able to compare two files and maybe even show a diff.

Comment: Like these? [Viewing and modifying hex data in file](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3408/185) / [Software tool for practical XOR comparisons (ASCII and HEX)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25627/185) (CrypTool2 is available for Linux)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hex diff viewers with console/terminal graphics:

- [**`vbindiff`**](http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/), Divides screen into top and bottom, no right/left view, fixed-width output.
- [**`hexdiff`**](http://tboudet.free.fr/hexdiff/), Same top/bottom look as `vbindiff`, fixed-width output, and it can be a hex *editor*.
- [**`dhex`**](http://www.dettus.net/dhex/) Top/bottom diff viewer, hex editor, resizable-width output, (fits terminal), and offers better navigation.

Graphical hex diff viewers:  I don't know of one, but here's a shell function using [**`mgdiff`**](https://pkgs.org/download/mgdiff), (which *has* left/right view), and `hexdump` (AKA `hd`), inefficiently:

```
mgdiffhex () 
{ 
    a="/tmp/$(basename "$1")$$.hex"
    b="/tmp/$(basename "$2")$$.hex"
    hd "$1" > "$a"
    hd "$2" > "$b"
    mgdiff "$a" "$b"
    rm     "$a" "$b"
}
```

Then run:

```
mgdiffhex foo bar
```

Notes: The `hexdump` util can be invoked with formatting options that allow for arbitrary terminal widths; `mgdiffhex` can be resized but lacks any means of reformatting the hex dumps within the resized window.  Combining them makes for a crude graphical hex diff viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wxHexEditor in Ubuntu repos.

https://github.com/EUA/wxHexEditor

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot showing the diff feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few GUI options, roughly in order of how much I'd recommend them:

##### [ImHex](https://imhex.werwolv.net/)

- This is a bit clunky but does seem to have some nice features and unlike some of the others is being actively developed
- To compare files:

  1. Open both of the files you want to compare
  2. *View* > *Diffing*
  3. Select each file to diff in the respective *Provider* dropdown

##### [wxHexEditor](http://www.wxhexeditor.org/)

- Not bad, but has a lot of bizarre defaults. Thankfully most of them can be worked around:

  - Unreadable default colour scheme (probably because of Ubuntu's default Gnome palette)

    - To change this: *Options* > *Preferences* > *Hex Colors*; I changed the last one to black to make it readable
  - Defaults to base-10 addresses

    - To change this: Right-click *Offset* column to switch to hex values (I don't see a way to change it in the *Comparison Results*)
  - When doing a diff of 2 files, by default it only scrolls one file

    - To change this, *Tools* > *Compare Files* and make sure you check *Connect files for scrolling*
  - Bytes per line is based on screen width

    - To change this: *Options* > *Preferences* > enable *Bytes Per Line Limit*
- To compare files:

  1. *Tools* > *Compare Files*
  2. Check *Connect files for scrolling* as mentioned above

##### [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/)

- Ghidra is a bit different since it's more of a reverse engineering tool than a hex editor, and it only shows one byte per line
- To compare files:

  1. Create a new project
  2. Import files into project
  3. Double-click file to open it in CodeBrowser
  4. Skip analysis when prompted
  5. *Tools* > *Program Differences*
  6. *Do Differences On* > deselect everything but *Bytes*
  7. You can also go to *Window* > *Bytes* to see a more typical hex editor view, but it will only show one file at a time

##### [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)

- This is a Windows tool but works fine in Wine. It's in this list because I've seen it mentioned as a visual binary diff tool in several places, but I don't actually recommend it:

  - Doesn't highlight differences between files
  - Handles differences byte-by-byte
  - Detects differences under the cursor for each file, which means if you click the cursor to a different location, it will compare a different location in each file
- To compare files:

  1. *Analysis* > *Data comparison* > *Compare*
  2. *Analysis* > *Data comparison* > *Next difference*